# Converting a VB6-like specification of a form into a Web page displaying the form

Tags: html, css, code-generation

As a part of my current pet project, I have to write an program that takes as input the specification of a form and generates as output the necessary HTML and CSS code to display the form as a Web page. The exact input format is irrelevant to this question, but the information it contains is similar to the information in a Visual Basic 6 form file, minus the Visual Basic code. In particular, the sizes and positions of the form's controls are represented as XY pairs in an absolute coordinate system.

The main problem I am facing is that I do not know how to map the *information* contained in the input format (control sizes and positions, tab order, etc.) to the *information* contained in the HTML and CSS files (when to use placeholder `div`s, when to use CSS floats, etc.).

I emphasize on the word *information* because I do of course know how to generate HTML- and CSS-*formatted* files given the information they should contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In particular, the sizes and positions of the form's controls are
>   represented as XY pairs in an absolute coordinate system.

In that case, the easiest method is to use [absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/1191-absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/R8K6u/

You should be able to directly map `width`/`height`/`left`/`top` from the VB6 equivalent.